# Equivalent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Two rectangular m-by-n matrices A and B Are equivalent if there exist an invertible m-by-m matrix P and an invertible n-by-n matrix Q such that PAQ=B.
If we define relation ~ as A~B if there exist an invertible m-by-m matrix P and an invertible n-by-n matrix Q such that PAQ=B.
I was able to prove that ~ is an equivalence relation.
How to find equivalence classes under this relation and the number of equivalence classes with using the basic concept of row transformations only?

Thank you

Comment: Just using $P$ you can reduce $A$ to reduced row echelon form. Using $Q$ also allows you column operations; can you reduce an echelon matrix even further with them?

Answer (score 3):

With row transformations, you can find for the matrix $A$ an [equivalent matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_equivalence) of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}
I_k & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$ where $I_k$ is the identity matrix of dimension $k \le \inf(n,m)$ where $(m,n)$ are the dimensions of the initial matrix $A$. **$k$ is the rank of the matrix $A$**.

Based on that, you get that the equivalent classes using the concept of row transformations are the matrices with a given rank.